# Select Directory with Python

Tags: python, directory, pyqt5

I want to select 5 images with Python so that I can use these imges in my python program. I tried to do this with QFileDialog() (PyQt5) but I only succeed to single select a file.
And how to select a folder is also not really comprehensive.

I just want to select 5 images and select a folder so that I can save files in that folder. But it seems to be not so easy to do that.
I really like Python because its so easy but PyQt5 makes me everytime I use it just aggressive, all other libraries are just nice and easy to understand.
Maybe there is a good alternative to pyqt? tkinter maybe?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select a folder you can use this code:

```
widget = QWidget()
dialog = QFileDialog(
    widget, "Select Directory of the Desired Files", os.path.curdir
)
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.DirectoryOnly)
```

Comment: QFileDialog(QWidget, Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_Frame'
  QFileDialog(parent: QWidget = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', filter: str = ''): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_Frame'

Comment: @marie1995 I have edited my answer. And PyQt is not that bad. You have to put the time to read the docs more carefully, which can be a little frustrating.

Comment: but the docs are not really explained in detail and also only for c++

Comment: @marie1995 pyqt also has its own docs, but they are usually not as detailed as the main Qt docs for C++. most of the flow of the Qt is preserved in PyQt, with the same class names and the same patterns. Reading those will definitely help you understand what is happening exactly, since PyQt is just a python wrapper for Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Qt supplies a bunch of static methods to get standardized file dialogs, two of them already satisfy your needs: [`getOpenFileNames()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileNames) (stress on the final "s") and [`getExistingDirectory()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory).

The first will return a list of absolute paths of selected file[s], the last will return the selected directory.

---

I know that reading the official documentation might be a bit overwhelming if you don't know anything about C++ (they *are* explained in detail, though), but they're not as hard as one could think.
Every function is listed in a very simple way:

```
returned_type : function_name(arguments) [const -> you can usually ignore this]
```

The returned_type is the type of the value the function is expected to return. In "c++ slang", `void` is the same as `return` (or `return None` or no return at all, as Python implicitly returns `None` if no other value/object is returned at the end of a function), if the type is a QString it's automatically converted to a Python `str`, while `qreal` is the same as Python's floats,. This is very important for "private" functions (methods), which are internally used by Qt: if you are subclassing and want to override a private method of a Qt class, you **have** to return the type Qt expects. You could theoretically ignore the `returned_type` for public functions if you know what you're doing, but it's usually better to stick with the original type.
There are some small "exceptions" that require some consideration. In some cases Qt expects some argument that will be modified within the function and would normally return whether the function was successful or not, while in Python it might return the reference to the argument (sorry, I can't remember them right now). Some other functions return a tuple instead of a single value, and that's the case of some static QFileDialog functions such as getOpenFileName[s] which return both the selected file[s] and the selected filter.